# Flutter JSON serialization error

Tags: json, dart, flutter

I want to serialize JSON objects to my native class objects from an incoming API request. However, when the mapping happens and the `FutureBuilder` tries to return data, it generates a runtime error as follows:

> *type _CastError is not a subtype of bool*

while using a list to return data and

> *type _TypeError is not a subtype of bool*

From the errors I am assuming that it is not able to cast the data from the stream. I don’t have many ideas as I am learning flutter.

Here is the future through which I am making a request:

```
Future getWeatherInfo(String city) async {
Uri uri = new Uri.https("api.apixu.com", "/v1/current.json",
  {"key": <key>, "q": city});
print(uri);
final response = await http.get(uri);
final responseJSON = jsonDecode(response.body);
print(responseJSON);
return BaseClass.getData(responseJSON);
```

**Native classes:**

```
class BaseClass {
// final WeatherInformation weatherInformation;
final Weather weather;
BaseClass({this.weather});
factory BaseClass.getData(Map jsonData) {
return new BaseClass(
  // weatherInformation: (jsonData["location"])
  //     .map((i) => WeatherInformation.weatherValues(i)),
  weather: (jsonData["current"])
      .map((i) => Weather.weatherData(i)),
);
}}


class WeatherInformation {
final String cityName;
final String cityRegion;
final String country;
final double lat;
final double long;
final String time;

WeatherInformation({
this.cityName,
this.cityRegion,
this.country,
this.time,
this.lat,
this.long,
});

factory WeatherInformation.weatherValues(Map data) {
  return new WeatherInformation(
  cityRegion: data['cityRegion'],
  cityName: data['name'],
  country: data['country'],
  lat: data['lat'],
  long: data['long'],
  time: data['localtime'],
);
}
}

class Weather {
final Condition condition;

final double windmph;
final double windkph;
final double winddegree;
final int cloud;
final double pressuremb;
final double pressurein;
final double precipmm;
final double precipin;
final int humidity;
final double centrigade;
final double faranheit;
final double tempc;
final double tempf;

Weather({
this.centrigade,
this.cloud,
this.faranheit,
this.humidity,
this.pressuremb,
this.tempc,
this.precipmm,
this.precipin,
this.pressurein,
this.tempf,
this.winddegree,
this.windkph,
this.windmph,
this.condition,
});

factory Weather.weatherData(Map data) {
return new Weather(
  tempc: data['temp_c'],
  tempf: data['temp_f'],
  windmph: data['wind_mph'],
  windkph: data['wind_kph'],
  winddegree: data['wind_degree'],
  pressuremb: data['pressure_mb'],
  pressurein: data['pressure_in'],
  precipmm: data['precip_mm'],
  precipin: data['precip_in'],
  humidity: data['humidity'],
  cloud: data['cloud'],
  centrigade: data['feelslike_c'],
  faranheit: data['feelslike_f'],
  // condition:
  //     (data['condition'] as List).map((i) => Condition.toJSON(i)).toList(),
);
}
}

class Condition {
String text;
String icon;

Condition({
Key key,
this.text,
this.icon,
});

Condition.toJSON(Map data)
  : icon = data['icon'],
    text = data['text'];
}
```

**ListView:**

```
** if (snapshot.hasError)** { //(previously was snapshot.error)
return new Center(
child: new Chip(
label: new Text('Error! Please try again',style: new TextStyle(color: 
Colors.white),)));
} else if (snapshot.hasData) {
return new ListView(
shrinkWrap:false,
children: <Widget>[
new ListTile(
leading: new Text("Calvin"),
                      title: new 
Text(snapshot.data.weather[0].tempc.toString(),
style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),),
new ListTile(
leading: new Text('Pressure'),
title: new Text(
snapshot.data.weather[0].pressurein.toString(),
style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
 ),
new ListTile(
title: new Text(snapshot.data.weather[0].cloud.toString()),
leading: new Icon(Icons.cloud)),
 ],
 );
 }
```

Comment: Where in the code are you getting the error? Do you have an `if` statement somewhere?

Comment: Yes,I am checking whether the snapshot has error or not, while building ListView.

Comment: Could you add that code to your question?

Comment: I was using the error property which returned Object :[

Comment: I wish they'd just log the field that errors, intead of keeping us in a guessing game.

Answer (score 0):

There is no type in the Future. Due to that, the `AsyncSnapshot` may not be working correctly.

Use `Future<BaseClass>` in the first listing above,

Then, in the `FutureBuilder` add it as follows:

```
new FutureBuilder<BaseClass>(
  future: getWeatherInfo(...),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<BaseClass> snapshot) {
....
```

Comment: Infact previously,I had set the type of future to BaseClass but I couldn't access the List and the class attributes so by default I left it dynamic

Comment: I got an exception which said _InternalLinkedHashmap<String,dynamic> is not a subtype of type List<dynamic>

Comment: Then you should try to solve this error. Somewhere you are passing a Map while it is expecting a List. Try to locate the line where that happens. Is `jsonData["current"]` in the factory a List or a Map? It should be a List if you are calling the `.map()`method on it.